# Polig-helman algorithm - if $g$ is a prim root mod $p$ does this mean that in the subproblems that all $A_i$ are prim roots mod $p$?

Tags: number-theory, congruences, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I am using the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm to solve a [*Discrete
Log Problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) to
find $x$ in

$$g^x = h \pmod{p}$$

Where $g, h$ are positive integers and p is prime.

Now presume g is a primitive root mod p, and p is $\beta-smooth$ (p-1 is easily factorised into product of small prime powers).

$N = p - 1 = \prod_{i=1}^{n} q_i^{e_i}$

We can summarize the necessary algorithm calculations in a handy table as

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \large q  & \large e & \large g^{(p-1)/q^e} mod p & \large h^{(p-1)/q^e} mod p &
\mbox{Solve}~ \large \left(g^{(p-1)/q^e} \right)^x = ~ \large
h^{(p-1)/q^e}~ \mbox{for} ~ \large x \\  \hline
q_1 & e_1 & A_1 & C_1 & \mbox{...}\\
   \hline
q_2 & e_2 & A_2 & C_2 & \mbox{...}\\  \hline
\end{array}$$
...

Questions:

Does $g$ being a primitive root mod p imply that all $A_i$ are primitive roots mod $p$? Why?
If there is such $g$ and $A_i$ s.t. $A_i$ is not a primitive root mod $p$, give an example of this.

Comment: How can you ask for more attention, when you refuse to pay any attention?

Comment: Patience is a virtue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have not abandoned it. I was waiting for more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what's going on in the table, $(A_i)^{q_i^{e_i}}=g^{p-1}=1$, so $A_i$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: Would you care to comment, unseen, as to whether I am on the right track?

Comment: I don't know the answer to my question so I don't know whether you are on the right track.

Comment: I thought I gave you the answer to your question. Your question was, are the $A_i$ all primitive roots modulo $p$. I have proved that $A_i$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$. If you need some further explanation, please tell me what you need.

Comment: That is all I need thank you